# How can i convert following code of PHP curl to JAVA HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, php

How can I convert following code of PHP curl to JAVA HttpURLConnection?

```java
$username = $_POST['username']; 
    $headers = array( 
    "Host: mail.google.com", 
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.0.4) Gecko/20060508 Firefox/1.5.0.4", 
    "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5", 
    "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5", 
    "Accept-Encoding: text", # No gzip, it only clutters your code! 
    "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", 
    "Date: ".date(DATE_RFC822) 
    ); 
    $c = curl_init('https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); // use authentication 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // send the headers 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // We need to fetch something from a string, so no direct output! 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // we get redirected, so follow 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1); // always stay authorised 
    $wrong = curl_exec($c); // Get it 
    curl_close($c); // Close the curl stream
```

Comment: i like to know why minus?? whats the problem with this question??

Comment: The problem is the question is not an actual, well-defined, question; you have shown no effort trying to resolve the problem yourself. It's of the "give me teh codez" variety.

Comment: who said i wasn't tried.i tried,i tried many times and failed,its above my knowledge,so i asked help...i think you dont know the answer so you are doing this

Comment: it's just one damn vote down, stop arguing, get over it and show your attempt.

Comment: seriously the down-vote sucks and I am giving it an upvote. It is a valid question which more people might like to know the answer to. That's what stackoverflow is about right?

Comment: @Alfred: that right...thks...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714296/2-legged-oauth-and-the-gmail-atom-feed

Comment: @BalusC: i am not using OAuth.so i asked how to do this in JAVA?

Comment: go to this link might be u will get solution
http://loopingrecursion.com/?t=php

Answer (score 1):

Use Commons Http Client library,it supports HttpGet, HttpPost also , you can add Request headers, etc..